# ObjectMapper toJSON() swift

Tags: swift, xcode, objectmapper

I have an object for which there are some properties in init func, while parsing data from JSON to object, it is doing great but while converting Object to JSON, i could not find way to convert that data in JSON

Following is code i'm using

```
var sOWSubCategory: SowSubCategoryModel?
var reportDisplayId : String?

required init?(map: Map){
        sOWSubCategory = SowSubCategoryModel(sOWSubCategoryID: map.JSON["SOWSubCategoryID"] as? Int, sOWSubCategoryNameAr: map.JSON["SOWSubCategoryNameAr"] as? String, sOWSubCategoryNameEn: map.JSON["SOWSubCategoryNameEn"] as? String)
        sOWSubCategoryDetail = SowSubCategoryDetailListModel(sOWSubCategoryDetailID: map.JSON["SOWSubCategoryDetailID"] as? Int64, sOWSubCategoryDetailAr: map.JSON["SOWSubCategoryDetailNameAr"] as? String, sOWSubCategoryDetailEn: map.JSON["SOWSubCategoryDetailNameEn"] as? String)
    }
func mapping(map: Map) {
    reportDisplayId <- map["ReportDisplayID"]   
}
```

**reportDisplayId** is being converted to JSON, but sOWSubCategory and sOWSubCategoryDetail are not

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectMapper` will `map` from/to the object properties used in the `mapping(map: Map)` method below

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    reportDisplayId <- map["ReportDisplayID"]   
}
```

As `reportDisplayId` is the only property getting mapped in `mapping(map: Map)` method so you are getting `JSON` with this key-value only. You should conform `SowSubCategoryModel` and `SowSubCategoryDetailListModel` to `Mappable` and map these objects through `mapping` method so that you just get the required JSON.

---

If you want to keep the mapping of `SowSubCategoryModel` and `SowSubCategoryDetailListModel` same as in question then you can implement `toJSON` method in your model by adding the `sOWSubCategory` and `sOWSubCategoryDetail` JSON as below,

```
func toJSON() -> [String : Any] {
    var finalJSON = self.toJSON()


    var sOWSubCategory = sOWSubCategory.toJSON()
    var sOWSubCategoryDetail = sOWSubCategoryDetail.toJSON()

    sOWSubCategory.forEach {
        finalJSON[$0.0] = $0.1
    }

    sOWSubCategoryDetail.forEach {
        finalJSON[$0.0] = $0.1
    }

    return finalJSON
}
```

Comment: I have added toJSON() method but this don't get called, I can't use SowSubCategoryModel as mappable due to some restrictions

Comment: If you can't conform `SowSubCategoryModel` to mappable then you can not get the auto converted JSON. You are left with manual creation, same as you are initializing this object.